# Como baixar uma image usando Pillow(python)

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como posso escolher onde meu `arquivo.png` será salvo usando `Img.save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o módulo `os` para escolher o local onde quer salvar o arquivo da seguinte forma:

```py
from os.path import join as pjoin
from PIL import Image
filename = "arquivo.png"
i = Image.open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/", filename)
path_to_file = pjoin("C:\\", "<local onde queira salvar>", filename)
i.save(path_to_file)
```

> **Nota:** No caso o primeiro argumento de `pjoin` é "C:\" pois estou considerando que voce usa Windows.

Comment: Vlw funcionou, porém estou com outro problema. Como faço pra que cada arquivo seja de um nome diferente? Tipo arquivo(1).png, arquivo(2).png.

Ou se não fazer apagar a imagem após 5s usando pillow

Comment: nesse caso a variável `filename` deveria receber um input do usuário perguntando qual o nome do arquivo. Não sei responder a sua segunda pergunta :(